# dplyr 0.7.5 change in select() behavior

Tags: r, dplyr

select() in dplyr 0.7.5 returns a different result from dplyr 0.7.4 when using a named vector to specify columns.

```
library(dplyr)                               
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15)
print(df)                                     
#>   a  b  c
#> 1 1  6 11
#> 2 2  7 12
#> 3 3  8 13
#> 4 4  9 14
#> 5 5 10 15

# a named vector
cols <- c(x = 'a', y = 'b', z = 'c')          
print(cols)                                   
#>  x   y   z 
#> "a" "b" "c"

# with dplyr 0.7.4
# returns column names with vector values
select(df, cols)                              
#>   a  b  c
#> 1 1  6 11
#> 2 2  7 12
#> 3 3  8 13
#> 4 4  9 14
#> 5 5 10 15

# with dplyr 0.7.5
# returns column names with vector names
select(df, cols)                              
#>   x  y  z
#> 1 1  6 11
#> 2 2  7 12
#> 3 3  8 13
#> 4 4  9 14
#> 5 5 10 15
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: I see in the release notes: "dplyr now depends on the new tidyselect package to power select(), rename(), pull() and their variants (#2896). " Could be an unintended side effect.

Comment: This may be obvious, and doesn't answer the question, but FYI you can return to old behavior with `select(df, unname(cols))`

Comment: `rename(df, cols) ` doesn't work though

Answer (score 1):

IMO it could have been **considered a bug in 0.7.4**, and is now fixed / more user-friendly.

With the move to `tidyselect`, the logic has become a little more sophisticated.
If you compare `dplyr::select_vars` to the new `tidyselect::vars_select` (these are the variants used by `dplyr:::select.data.frame` in 0.7.4 and 0.7.5 respectively), you can find that the line below was losing the names for the **named & quoted** (strings) case in 0.7.4:

```
ind_list <- map_if(ind_list, is_character, match_var, table = vars)

# example:
dplyr:::select.data.frame(mtcars, c(a = "mpg", b = "disp"))
```

Note that this is **not an issue of named vectors in general**, as the typical unquoted case was always fine:

```
dplyr:::select.data.frame(mtcars, c(a = mpg, b = disp))
# (here the names are indeed "a" and "b" afterwards)
```

There is a line of code that handles the usage of `c()`:

```
ind_list <- map_if(ind_list, !is_helper, eval_tidy, data = names_list)
```

`eval_tidy` is from the `rlang` package, and in the line above would return the following for the problematic call:

```
[[1]]
 a      b 
 "mpg" "disp"
```

---

Now with `tidyselect`, we have some extra handling, see https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyselect/blob/master/R/vars-select.R.

In particular, `vars_select_eval` has the following line, where it is handling the usage of `c()`:

```
ind_list <- map_if(quos, !is_helper, overscope_eval_next, overscope = overscope)
```

`overscope_eval_next` is again from the `rlang` package and calls the same routine as `eval_tidy` would, but it receives an *overscope* variant of `c()` that handles strings (through the `overscope` argument). See `tidyselect:::vars_c`.
So after this line, the `c(a = "mpg", b = "disp")` case becomes the same as `c(a = mpg, b = disp)`:

```
[[1]]
a b   # these are the names
1 3   # these are the positions of the selected cols
```

`is_character` then does not hold anymore in subsequent code, as opposed to above with `rlang::eval_tidy`.

In case you look at these functions in `rlang`, the fact that `overscope_eval_next` is soft-deprecated in favor of `eval_tidy` might confuse you given the above. But here I guess that `tidyselect` just hasn't been "cleaned up" wrt this yet (naming inconsistencies etc would have to be addressed as well, so it's a re-write of more than just the one line with the call). But in the end `eval_tidy` can be used in the same way now and probably will be.